# How to split a string with multi-character delimiter in vb - asp.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, string

How should I split a string separated by a multi-character delimiter in VB?

i.e. If my string is say - Elephant##Monkey, How do I split it with "##" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
Dim words As String() = myStr.Split(new String() { "##" }, 
                                        StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Answer (score 5):

here in VB.NET

```
Dim s As String = "Elephant##Monkey1##M2onkey"
Dim a As String() = Split(s, "##", , CompareMethod.Text)
```

ref : [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28VS.80%29.aspx) check the Alice and Bob example.

Comment: "alice and bob" answers refers to microsoft.visualbasic.split method, instead of system.text.replace method.  But, it's a good one too!  microsoft.visualbasic is packed with lot of useful utilities that even c# users can use.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx).

```
string whole = "Elephant##Monkey";
string[] split = Regex.Split(whole, "##");
foreach (string part in split)
    Console.WriteLine(part);
```

Be careful however, because this isn't just a string, it's a complete Regular Expression. Some characters might need escaping, etc. I suggest you look them up.

UPDATE- Here is the corresponding VB.NET code:

```
Dim whole As String = "Elephant##Monkey"
Dim split As String() = Regex.Split(whole, "##")
For Each part As String In split
    Console.WriteLine(part)
Next
```

Comment: This example is C#, I don't speak VB, but you shouldn't have any trouble converting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim s As String = "Elephant##Monkey"
    Dim parts As String() = s.Split(New Char() {"##"c})

            Dim part As String
    For Each part In parts
        Console.WriteLine(part)
    Next
```